# Using Azure.Storage.Blobs to generate SAS expiring tokens with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

Having some trouble with this one. I'm getting an SAS token generated after following the examples in Microsoft's documentation, but am having issues with the SAS token not being authenticated.

```
string sastoken = "";
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=accountname;AccountKey=accountkey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
            string containerName = containername;
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow + (new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0)),
                BlobContainerName = containerName,
                BlobName = imageData.filename,
                Resource = "b"
            };

            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read);
            sastoken = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new StorageSharedKeyCredential(containername, credentialkey)).ToString();

            UriBuilder fulluri = new UriBuilder()
            {
                Scheme = "https",
                Host = string.Format("{0}.blob.core.windows.net", containername),
                Path = string.Format("{0}/{1}", "blobtest", "file.bmp"),
                Query = sastoken
            };

            imageData.url = fulluri.Uri.ToString();
```

imageData.url returns as: https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/file.bmp?sv=2019-07-07&se=2020-07-10T14%3A54%3A43Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=UXvC7SAXqQtsVgfXj6L%2BOIinTMhQj%2F3NH95v%2FLRvM8g%3D

I get an authentication error, but the entire point of SAS tokens is to provide that authentication. I'm sure that I'm missing something here, but haven't found anywhere that I'm making a mistake. Most of the information I find is related to the Microsoft.Azure.Storage package rather than the Azure.Storage.Blob namespace. Any help or advice would be welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: This can be due to time difference between the server processing your request and the client. Try to set the `sasBuilder.StartsOn` property to an earlier time and see whether that helps. Something like: sasBuilder.StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).

Comment: I've tried that, using a 24 hour buffer in both directions. The result is the same unfortunately.

Comment: Can you confirm the blob container name and blob name are the same as what you’re using in creating the URL. Otherwise your code looks ok to me.

Comment: Looks like you generate your SAS token for `image.filename`, but your URL is always uses static `blobtest` and `file.bmp`. Do you want to change those to use the dynamic values and try that way?

Comment: Yes, the container and blob names are correct between the request and the produced url. They are both also correct in line with my Azure Storage account and blob.

Comment: Artak you should make that an actual answer. Yes, I was doing something absolutely idiotic and you found it. Code bias sucks. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, great. Will post that shortly! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your generated SAS token and URL are using different values for account name, container name and blob name.
Consider updating the URL generation code to use the same values.

```cs
UriBuilder fulluri = new UriBuilder()
{
  Scheme = "https",
  Host = string.Format("{0}.blob.core.windows.net", accountname),
  Path = string.Format("{0}/{1}", containerName, imageData.fileName),
  Query = sastoken
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I use something like this, using the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` nuget package:

```cs
private Uri GetSasForBlob(CloudBlob blob, DateTime expiry, SharedAccessBlobPermissions permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.None)
{
    var offset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    var policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
    {
        SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(offset),
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = expiry.Add(offset),
                Permissions = permissions
    };
#pragma warning disable CA5377 // Use Container Level Access Policy
    var sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
#pragma warning restore CA5377 // Use Container Level Access Policy
    return new Uri($"{blob.Uri}{sas}");
}
```

---

UPDATE using `Azure.Storage.Blobs`:

```cs
// Read these from config:
// var accountName = "accountname";
// var accountKey = "xxxxxxx";
// var blobServiceEndpoint = $"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net";


private Uri GetSasForBlob(string blobname, string containerName, DateTime expiry, BlobAccountSasPermissions permissions = BlobAccountSasPermissions.Read)
{
    var offset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

    var credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
    var sas = new BlobSasBuilder
    {
        BlobName = blobname,
        BlobContainerName = containerName,
        StartsOn = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(offset),
        ExpiresOn = expiry.Add(offset)
    };
    sas.SetPermissions(permissions);

    UriBuilder sasUri = new UriBuilder($"{blobServiceEndpoint}/{containerName}/{blobname}");
    sasUri.Query = sas.ToSasQueryParameters(credential).ToString();

    return sasUri.Uri;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/42839e7dea6be316024f168ecd08f3134bc57a47/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/samples/Sample02_Auth.cs#L137

Comment: This is using Microsoft.Azure.Storage, which is replaced by Azure.Storage.Blobs

Comment: Code in your answer makes use of the older SDK whereas OP is using the new SDK.

Comment: Can you please expand on generating a literal token not an URI?

Comment: @Vivere `sas.ToSasQueryParameters(credential).ToString()` generates a SAS signature. Although you'll almost always want the URL. If you were asking how to get a string literal out of the `Uri`, you can use [`uri.AbsoluteUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.absoluteuri?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Since a year or 2 there is official migration guidance docs available. These also expose the existence of a convenience method for generating a sas token url.

```
// Create a BlobClient with a shared key credential
BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(blobUri, sharedKeyCredential);

Uri sasUri;
// Ensure our client has the credentials required to generate a SAS
if (blobClient.CanGenerateSasUri)
{
    // Create full, self-authenticating URI to the resource from the BlobClient
    sasUri = blobClient.GenerateSasUri(BlobSasPermissions.Read, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1));

    // Use newly made as SAS URI to download the blob
    await new BlobClient(sasUri).DownloadToAsync(new MemoryStream());
}
```

This example and more can be found here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/AzureStorageNetMigrationV12.md#generate-a-sas